# How to get Heroku Local to display for logging information in the server log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku

When I run my rails app locally using Heroku local the server log messages get trimmed like so:

```
3:17:01 PM web.1  |  ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the valu…
3:17:01 PM web.1  |    app/controllers/surveys_controller.rb:42:in `survey_params'
```

It makes it very hard for me to debug issues.  Is there any easy fix for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a while researching this and it seems that the problem is with the underlying "Forego" library that Heroku Toolbelt uses.  I started my web server with Foreman and was able to get full logging back.

Answer (score 0):

`heroku local` recently [switched](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-local/pull/13) to node-foreman, which seems to fix a bunch of random little bugs from forego & foreman on my system. Does ~/.heroku/node_modules/heroku-local/package.json show a version that's at least 5.0?

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even realize this truncation was happening now. I filed a bug about it: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-local/issues/17